# error Your serialized closure might have been modified or it's unsafe to be unserialized. luego de modificar env key en laravel

Tags: laravel

estaba levantando un proyecto ya iniciado en laravel y al querer acceder por localhost tenía un error diciendo que la API key no estaba, usé el comando para generar un nuevo archivo .env `cp .env.example .env`, luego usé el comando `sail artisan key:generate` para generar la key y por último un `sail artisan config:cache`, sin embargo, ahora obtengo el error

```
Laravel\SerializableClosure\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException
Your serialized closure might have been modified or it's unsafe to be unserialized.
http://localhost/
```

todos los demás parámetros del .env están exactamente igual que antes de volver a generar el archivo, cómo lo puedo solucionar?

estoy corriéndolo en docker y ubuntu, por eso el comando es sail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la serialización en PHP devuelve una representación reversible de un objeto como string. La reversibilidad indica que la salida de `deserialize` sobre esa cadena es un objeto con el mismo **estado** que el que serializaste al principio (también puede ser un escalar, pero es trivial serializar escalares).

Cuando serializas la instancia de una clase, la representación serializada contiene las variables de instancia, no los métodos. Al deserializarla, PHP no invocará al constructor. En la práctica, en el intertanto puedes redefinir la clase y declarar algunas propiedades como privadas, y sin embargo al deserializar ahí estarán, definidas con el valor que serializaste al inicio.

Aunque eso no es todo lo que hay que saber antes de experimentar con esas funciones, lo importante es que hay objetos que no se pueden serializar, como los `resource` y las `closures`. Otros objetos no se serializan bien a menudo porque son envoltorios de un resource (como DOMDocument y SimpleXMLElement).

PHP no permite serializar closures, entre otras cosas porque no hay nada que serializar, si no tienen estado.

Como Laravel, entre sus mecanismos de optimización, permite almacenar las rutas precompiladas (en `bootstrap/cache/routes-<version>.php`) esa serialización no es nativa sino que utiliza [SerializableClosure](https://github.com/laravel/serializable-closure)

Si tú miras el README de esa librería, muestran que la buena práctica es que al serializar una función anónima le pongas clave

```
use Laravel\SerializableClosure\SerializableClosure;

$closure = fn () => 'james';

// Recommended
SerializableClosure::setSecretKey('secret');

$serialized = serialize(new SerializableClosure($closure));
```

Para esto Laravel usa la APP_KEY. Si regeneraste la APP_KEY, la nueva ya no sirve para hidratar el contenido de `bootstrap/cache/xxx.php`, tal como tampoco servirá para usar `decrypt` sobre cadenas encriptadas con la key anterior.

Para deshacerte del error podrías probar `php artisan route:clear`. Como hay varios elementos que se pueden cachear y limpiar con artisan, a lo mejor tendrás que probar también con las vistas, los eventos y el cache, o bien  borrar todos los scripts php dentro de `bootstrap/cache` dado que tu copia no debiera tenerlos si no tienes el `.env` que corresponde.